# Create and fill properties of a object of class T or extended from T without duplicate code

Tags: java, casting, subclass, pojo, entities

I've developed a Java EE app offering REST services. I've decided to never expose underlying entities, using POJOs to send data. When the user asks for a list, the app sends a list of POJOs with minimal information, but if the user asks for a specific resource he will get a more detailed POJO. 
For example, imagine I have a `Car` entity, I can have this:

```
public class BaseCar {
    private String model;
    private int year;
    // [...getters and setters...]
}
```

and this:

```
public class FullCar extends BaseCar {
    private String color;
    private int maxSpeed;
    private List<String> comments;
    // [...getters and setters...]
}
```

So if the user calls /cars he will obtain a list of `BaseCar`s, but if he calls /cars/10 he obtain a `FullCar`. Actually I've two methods for creating BaseCar and FullCar:

```
public BaseCar toBaseCar(Car car) {
    BaseCar baseCar = new BaseCar();
    baseCar.setModel(car.getModel());
    baseCar.setYear(car.getYear());
}

public FullCar toFullCar(Car car) {
    FullCar fullCar = new FullCar();
    fullCar.setModel(car.getModel());
    fullCar.setYear(car.getYear());
    fullCar.setColor(car.getColor());
    fullCar.setMaxSpeed(car.getMaxSpeed());
    fullCar.setComments(new ArrayList<String>());
    for (Comment comment : car.getCommentsCollection()) {
        fullCar.getComments().add(comment.getText());
    }
}
```

As you can see, there's repeated code (in this example only `setModel()` and `setYear()`, but usually it is more). I know what I can do to avoid these repetitions:

```
BaseCar baseCar = (baseCar) toFullCar(car);
```

But I don't want to do it, because I don't want to use more memory or load collections if I'm not going to use them. In fact, what I wish is something like this:

```
public FullCar toFullCar(Car car) {
    FullCar fullCar = toBaseCar(car);
    fullCar.setColor(car.getColor());
    fullCar.setMaxSpeed(car.getMaxSpeed());
    fullCar.setComments(new ArrayList<String>());
    for (Comment comment : car.getCommentsCollection()) {
        fullCar.getComments().add(comment.getText());
    }
}
```

But casting from `BaseCar` to `FullCar` is not possible. Is there a way to avoid repeating the same block of code (sometimes quite large)?

Answer (score 2):

Add a constructor to the `BaseCar` and the `FullCar`  that take a `Car` parameter:

```
interface Car {
    String getModel();

    int getYear();

    String getColor();

    int getMaxSpeed();

    List<String> getComments();

}

public class BaseCar {
    private String model;
    private int year;

    public BaseCar(Car c) {
        this.model = c.getModel();
        this.year = c.getYear();
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

}

public class FullCar extends BaseCar {
    private String color;
    private int maxSpeed;
    private List<String> comments;

    public FullCar(Car c) {
        super(c); // Set up base car.
        this.maxSpeed = c.getMaxSpeed();
        this.color = c.getColor();
        this.comments = new ArrayList<>(c.getComments());
    }

}

public BaseCar toBaseCar(Car car) {
      return new BaseCar(car);
}

public FullCar toFullCar(Car car) {
    return new FullCar(car);
}
```

Comment: This is a good idea and I've already think about it, but not always I have a 1:1 relationship between entities and pojo and I'm not sure putting logic in a class I use only for sharing data. I mean, of course I can, but I don't like it.